# Google hasn’t verified this app warning for google contacts api request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-contacts-api

I am using google contacts api to get the contacts but everytime it shows the 'Unverified' consent screen,even though I allowed it many times. I skipped the verification process for the app in google console because I am not using any sensitive scopes and so didn't add any scopes to OAuth consent screen.

N.B. In my another project with the same configuration and no scopes added, everything is working fine with no unverified consent warning.

Answer (score 0):

#### What you are experiencing is the expected behavior in this situation.

The **Unverified app screen** appears due to the following reasons:

> - Your app uses sensitive or restricted scopes and you haven't configured them in your OAuth consent screen configuration page and requested verification.
> - Your app uses sensitive or restricted scopes that you haven't selected on the OAuth consent screen configuration page.
> - You selected sensitive or restricted scopes on the OAuth consent screen configuration page and requested verification, but the verification is not yet complete.

Moreover, it's important to note the following as well:

> When the scopes requested in your app code differ from the scopes requested in your OAuth consent screen configuration page, your users see an "unverified app" screen. Make sure that scopes you request in your app are the same as what's in your OAuth consent screen.

As for the **sensitive scopes**, you can determine them by simply looking for the lock icon in the Cloud Console of your project.

#### Reference

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865);
- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).